How can I click on DONE button?
Eclipse/Java with selenium; I"d want to click on DONE button
I have tried this driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[aria-label='Done. Search for round trip flights, departing on March 15, 2025 and returning on April 15, 2025']")).click();

I used a more generic version of a CSS selector,
button[aria-label^='Done.']

With a WebDriverWait, the full code would be
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[aria-label^='Done.']"))).click();


Bravo! Thanks @JeffC
